# Get notified about audit events in linux

Tags: linux, system-calls, android-source, audit

I am using auditd to define some events I want to audit e.g.

```
./auditctl -w /some/local/folder -p wa -k MyRule
```

which when e.g. I create a file in the folder results in

> 2021-08-30 15:30:34.160 24217-24217/? W/sh: type=1300 audit(0.0:60421): arch=c00000b7 syscall=56 success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=71a6e2aa88 a2=241 a3=1b6 items=2 ppid=23092 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts1 ses=4294967295 exe="/system/bin/sh" subj=u:r:su:s0 key="MyRule"

I am looking for ways to get notified about those events, preferably programmatically.

I am running on a custom AOSP, in that repo, but I'm OK with trying "regular" linux solutions too (as those might be piped into something that can work on android).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **cron** to periodiacally invoke [auserach](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ausearch.8.html) specifying an start and end time (`--start`, `--end`) and then do whatever you want to send notifications, perhapas firing intents.